# how to remove OrchardLocal from Orchard URL?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I just downloaded the latest source codes of orchard.  I run the solution using vs 2012.  I am getting this URL in my browser.

```
http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/
```

Is there a way I can remove "OrchardLocal" from the URL.  when I push the app to the production server. I dont want to see http://test.com/OrchardLocal/

Comment: Right click Orchard.Web and select properties then go to Web. Should be able to edit it there. However when pushing to server you shouldn't see OrchardLocal... I think ^_^

Comment: @Hazza thanks alot. I thought its in the code, no wonder I cannot find.  please answer my question, so I can give you credits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click Orchard.Web and select properties then go to Web. Should be able to edit it there. However when pushing to server you shouldn't see OrchardLocal... I think ^_^